# SVG icon shows in dev but not in production mode

Tags: angular

In my app.component.ts, I register my svg icon as follows

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('excel',
  this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../assets/microsoft-excel.svg'));
  }
}
```

In my html, I use the icon as follows:

```
<mat-icon class="custom-svg-icon" svgIcon="excel"></mat-icon>
```

CSS is:

```
::ng-deep .custom-svg-icon {
  svg {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

This icon shows in dev mode. But whenever I build in production, I get a below error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

It can't find the svg icon.  However, when I checked `dist` directory I found my icon under the `assets` folder.

My angular version is 7.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Try adding the svg icon in your assets folder in the angular.json (angular-cli.json)

Comment: It seems to be a similar problem, as described here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4806 or https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3132. Some of these is working for you?

Comment: I had quite similar problem. Long story short try to add '/' at the begining of the asset link.

Comment: I just realize the issue is not in angular side... it's on the server side cause i implemented the resource handler to always serve index.html, i forgot to add `"/**/assets/*.svg"` in the list of static resources.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on whether are you copying your assets folder to dist folder or not.

If you doing it, verify your path. seems either folder is not there or path is wrong.
Below is code to be added in webpack.config.js to copy assets folder.
For path, verify where this assets folder got copied in **BUILD**.

```
module.exports = {
 plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: 'src/assets', to:'assets'}
  ])
 ]
}
```

Comment: i think your answer is very dated.  i'm using angular-cli.  besides i already mentioned in the question that the icon is in the assets folder in the package.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the svg icon in your assets folder in the angular.json (angular-cli.json)

```
"assets": [
        "src/assets",
        "src/assets/microsoft-excel.svg"
        ...etc...
      ],
```

consider adding the entire path to the assets array even if it has src/assets.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the icon is already inside the assets folder.  in angular.json, `"assets": [
              "src/assets"]`... angular-cli.json is from old version of angular

Comment: I knew that you mentioned. But consider adding the entire path to the assets array even if it has src/assets.